# Mysql design for "favorites" entity

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP application using MySQL as a store. The application serves multiple services ( for example cruises and hotels ) and I want to implement Favorites.

I can't figure it out how to make it simple. The silliest way is to create two different favorites tables for each service, or to put them all in table, but using the second way I'm not sure how to join the other tables in one query.

For example: user A have two favorites: 1 hotel and 1 cruise, so the query will looks something like:

```
SELECT id..ect FROM favorites 
LEFT JOIN hotels on ? = ? 
LEFT JOIN cruises on ? = ? 
WHERE user_id = ? AND ( this is very important ) language_id = 1
```

Tables cruises and hotels use auto increment primary key as id, so as you can assume, the id wont be relevant in this case.

EDIT:
Sorry, I was not very accurate.. The users will be able to select hotels, cruises and etc as favorites and be able to book them later. What I want is to know which is the best way to go and is it possible to select them from the database with one query

Comment: What are the users able to Favorite? I am not quite sure what the current situation is and the desired situation.

Comment: Post your curent schema so we can understand what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your favorite table must have user ID, source table (code for cruise or hotel), and Id to the cruise or hotel table.

Then select with union.

```
Select Id, 'H', hotel_name,... 
From favorite 
Join hotel on hotel.id = favorite.id and favorite.rectype = 'H' 
Where userID =? 
Union
Select Id, 'C', cruise_name,... 
From favorite 
Join cruise on cruise.id = favorite.id and favorite.rectype = 'C' 
Where userID =?
```

When using the union the number, type, & name of columns must match above & below. If needed you can obviously leave some empty in one or the other.

Comment: From performance point of view, which one will be faster, this one or with one select and multiple joins

Comment: The one will take 0.023 seconds and the other will take 0.028 seconds. I forget which takes the additional 5 one-thousandths of a second. But unless you are planning on getting millions of records I wouldn't be too stressed over it. Personally I would go with readability and maintainability which for me is better when I have a single table with a code.

Comment: Wait, how would you do it with one select and multiple joins? Is that one of the options here?

Comment: Actually the result with multple joins in one query is not working as expected.. so yes.. I'll need the union operator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two intersect tables, hotels_favorites and cruises_favorites.  This keeps your favorites agnostic.  It also opens up the possibility that the favorite could be shared between the two.

```
#hotels_favorites
#----------------
# -favorite_id (fk to favorite)
# -hotel_id (fk to hotel)

#cruises_favorites
#----------------
# -favorite_id (fk to favorite)
# -cruise_id (fk to cruise)
```

Comment: Yes, just one question, what happens if i want to add more services in the futures, need to create tables again and change queries. Is this okay ?

Comment: Anton - exactly.  If you add another entity type in the future, you would want to create another intersect table.  That is a completely reasonable design.  It will allow your design to grow flexibly. Don't forget that you can create views on top of these linked tables to abstract out the normalization.